# Adding more html pages to node server

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, node.js

i wanna add another html page which i could route to con and read temp like i do in index.html

```
    var http = require('http');
var ejs = require('ejs');
var fs = require('fs');
var system = require('child_process').exec;



var content = fs.readFileSync('index.html', 'utf-8');
var compiled = ejs.compile(content);
http.createServer(function(req,res) {
      var temp = 5;

     if(req.url === "/con") {
          console.log("You are in con");
    }
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.end(compiled({temp: temp}));
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: as i Can see in your code. you are synchronized with index.html and if the request uri is con you are displaying a You are in con message, now what you wish to add to that ?

Comment: Another HTMLwhich i will link to it using a button from the index page and the new HTML page could route to /con ,too

Comment: Just create a new function to wrap all the  'if(req.url === "/xxx"){} else if(){} else ....' or using a dictionary of function "{'/xxx': functionA, '/xx2': functionB}".

Comment: And do "fs.readFileSync, res.end, etc" inside those function (functionA, functionB)

Comment: How ? 
could you explain with code, please.
@KitFung

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xsh9e1xp/1/

Comment: nextRender is not defined @KitFung

Comment: sorry for the typo mistake, it should be 'nextPageRender'

Comment: moreover, it is just a sample. You should make it more systematic according to your need.

Comment: I did, but there is a problem by routing to next 
TypeError: Property '/next' of object #<Object> is not a function
@KitFung

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xsh9e1xp/2/

Comment: It is about the order of function, I have updated it. It should work now

Comment: Thank you @KitFung
one last thing i just wanna the server accept the /con as a route not to give 404 error, i tried to tyb it in the route variable without calling any function, but it gives me an error.
So what i need is to route to /con without calling any thing

Comment: You really need to call something, at least a function that just call "res.end()"; Otherwise, the request will be hold up by the server forever.